# How many ways can the image be properly colored with at most q colors?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

[image]

so the actual question is about the 8 regions of Iceland's political map, I just remapped it where each vertex is a different region and the edges represent which regions it boarders.The way I attempted to do this was to pick a point and give it q colors to go from then continue picking points based off the previous.  So I picked point 6 to start with. So 6 had q choices, 4 had q-1, 5 had q-2, 3 had q-3, 2 had q-2, 7 had q-2, 8 had q-2, and 1 had q-2. The problem with this is if I had gone to 1 before 7, it would have altered the result.  So I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $3,4,5$, and $6$ are a copy of $K_4$ and will require $4$ different colors, so we must have $q\ge 4$, and it’s easy to check that $4$ colors suffice for the whole graph. We might as well begin by coloring those four vertices; this can be done in $q(q-1)(q-2)(q-3)$ ways. There are then $q-2$ ways to color vertex $2$.

It’s necessary to consider vertex $7$ next: it must differ from both vertices $2$ and $6$, so $q-2$ colors are available for it, and the same is then true for each of vertices $1$ and $8$. The total number of colorings is therefore $q(q-1)(q-2)^5(q-3)$.

Considering vertex $1$ before vertex $7$ doesn’t actually alter the result, though it does make it harder to compute. It’s true that at that point there are $q-1$ choices for vertex $1$, but one of them is the color used for vertex $6$. If we give vertex $1$ that color, there are $q-2$ choices available for vertex $7$; if we give it one of the other $q-2$ available colors, there are only $q-3$ choices available for vertex $7$. Thus, there are

$$1\cdot(q-2)+(q-2)(q-3)=(q-2)^2$$

ways to choose colors for vertices $1$ and $7$, exactly the same result that we got by considering vertex $7$ before vertex $1$. And by either approach there are still $q-2$ choices for vertex $8$.

If anyone’s curious, I believe that the regions are as follows:

$(1)$ Vesturland
$(2)$ Vestfirðir
$(3)$ Norðurland vestra
$(4)$ Norðurland eystra
$(5)$ Austurland
$(6)$ Suðurland
$(7)$ Höfuðborgarsvæði
$(8)$ Suðurnes

Comment: Wow! You is brilliant sir. Thanks for enlighten us with ur responses everyday sir.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm Brian's answer and to introduce a slightly more methodical approach. What you want is the [chromatic polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial), which satisfies a simple recurrence on edge deletion and contraction $P_G = P_{G-e} - P_{G/e}$. Note the point graph $P_{\bullet}(q) = q$ and that contraction $/e$ does not introduce multiple edges or self-loops (as it does in the recurrence for the Tutte polynomial). One trick for hand calculation is to replace exterior triangles with the factor $(q-2)$, as seen in the first line of the image below. The second and third line serve as examples (since we already know $P_{K_n}(q) = q \, (q-1) \ldots (q-n+1) = q^{\underline{n}}$).

$\qquad \qquad$                                                                                                           [image]